# How to remove all the items from MongoDB except last N using Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, nestjs

I am using NestJS to keep logic and history of Calculator. So the point is I want to keep only last 10 cases in DB. But don't know how to do it. Let's take a look. Here's my **history.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class HistoryService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(HistoryItem.name)
    private historyModel: Model<HistoryItemDocument>,
  ) {}
  async create(dto: CreateHistoryItemDto): Promise<HistoryItem> {
    const historyItem = await this.historyModel.create({ ...dto });
    return historyItem;
  }
  async getAll(): Promise<HistoryItem[]> {
    const allHistoryItems = await this.historyModel
      .find()
      .sort({ _id: -1 }) //Here I sort the items to get the latest ones
      .limit(maxNumberOfDBItemsToDisplay);   
//Here I limit number of items to send it to Client

    return allHistoryItems;
  }
  async getOne(id: ObjectId): Promise<HistoryItem> {
    const historyItem = await this.historyModel.findById(id);
    return historyItem;
  }
  async delete(id: ObjectId): Promise<ObjectId> {
    const historyItem = await this.historyModel.findByIdAndDelete(id);
    return historyItem.id;
  }
}
```

As you see I can get 10 last items from DB. But how to remove the rest to keep base updated only with 10 last cases?

Comment: You could be looking for [capped collection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/capped-collections/)

Comment: @ray I would be appreciated if you can help me with this. I understood, that capped collection is an excellent decision for me. But I don't know how to reassign my existing collection to make it capped.

Comment: Can you try [this example from official document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/capped-collections/#convert-a-collection-to-capped)?

Comment: @ray Yes, I have seen the manual. But like I said, I use Nest.JS to work with MongoDB. And there is no such code in Nest.JS. The DB is accessed via ```MongooseModule.forRoot("urlToCollection")```. Therefore, I do not quite understand where to use this code from the manual ```db.runCommand({"convertToCapped": "mycoll", size: 100000});``` to solve the problem.

Comment: oh, you can simply run the command in a [mongodb shell](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/#mongodb-binary-bin.mongosh). If you have some db client to help you look into the db, they should have one associated.

Comment: You may want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75365097/14732669) to see the usage of `cappedMax` argument.