# MongoDB convert to capped collection - unexpected collection size

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB v6.0.3 setup. I am trying to convert a normal, prepopulated collection (with 10 documents) into a capped collection of size 5.

#### The scripts I used:

```js
db.testCollection.drop();

db.testCollection.insertMany([
    {"key": 1},
    {"key": 2},
    {"key": 3},
    {"key": 4},
    {"key": 5},
    {"key": 6},
    {"key": 7},
    {"key": 8},
    {"key": 9},
    {"key": 10},
]);

db.runCommand({"convertToCapped": "testCollection", size: 5});
```

But when I am verifying the result, I get an output of 8 documents instead of the expected 5 documents:

```js
db.testCollection.countDocuments(); // output: 8

db.testCollection.find(); // output: document with key from 3 to 10
```

#### What I have tried:

1. use another MongoDB v5.0.3 to verify the behaviour: same result
2. insert some more records to see if it will return to expected 5 documents: same result

```js
db.testCollection.insertOne({"key": 11});

db.testCollection.countDocuments(); // output: 8

db.testCollection.find(); // output: document with key from 4 to 11
```

3. [changing the capped collection size](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/capped-collections/#change-a-capped-collection-s-size) in v6.0.3 setup: same result

```js
db.runCommand( { collMod: "testCollection", cappedSize: 5 } )
```

Any explanation for this unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `size` field represents the maximum size of the collection in **bytes**, which MongoDB will pre-allocate for the collection. If the size field is less than or equal to 4096, then the collection will have a cap of 4096 bytes. Otherwise, MongoDB will raise the provided size to make it an integer multiple of 256.

In your case you should use `max` field which specifies a maximum number of documents for the collection.

**Note**

> The size argument is always required, even when you specify max number of documents. MongoDB will remove older documents if a collection reaches the maximum size limit before it reaches the maximum document count.

You query should be somewhat like below:

- If you want to create a new capped collection.

  ```bash
  db.createCollection("testCollection", { capped: true, size: 4096, max: 5 })
  ```
- If you want to convert a collection to capped.

  ```bash
  db.runCommand({"convertToCapped": "testCollection", size: 4096, max: 5});
  ```
- If you want to change a capped collection's size.

  ```bash
  db.runCommand( { collMod: "testCollection", cappedSize: 4096 } )
  ```
- If you want to change the maximum number of documents in a capped collection.

  ```bash
  db.runCommand( { collMod: "testCollection", cappedMax: 5} )
  ```

**Note**

> ***Queries are supported in Mongodb version 6.0***

[Reference](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/capped-collections)